# auto high Panel-Body with text

Tags: php, html, css

Hi i have the following Problem see Picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1o1ld.jpg

How can i manage it that the size fits to the text ? the code looks like this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<strong>Anonym</strong>&nbsp
<a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span></a>&nbsp
<!--<a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>&nbsp-->
<a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<p><?php echo $Question;?></p>
</div><!-- /panel-body -->
</div><!-- /panel panel-default -->
<?php } ?>
<!--Hier neues Element Einfügen/Ende -->
</div><!-- /col-sm-6 -->
<div class="col-sm-6">
```

Thanks for some solutions :)

CSS Looks like This :

```
.panel {
    position:relative;
}
.panel>.panel-heading:after,.panel>.panel-heading:before{
    position:absolute;
    top:11px;left:-16px;
    right:100%;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    display:block;
    content:" ";
    border-color:transparent;
    border-style:solid solid outset;
    pointer-events:none;
}
.panel>.panel-heading:after{
    border-width:7px;
    border-right-color:#f7f7f7;
    margin-top:1px;
    margin-left:2px;
}
.panel>.panel-heading:before{
    border-right-color:#ddd;
    border-width:8px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

It allows long words (you have one word in each) to break

Comment: Does it also work if i have a normal Text and Not only a Single word? :)

Comment: Normal text should break by default. Try outputting a normal text and see if there is even a problem. There should not be.

Comment: Thanks Works Great :)